# Why Windows 10 phone backspace doesn't work properly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm writing an app that will have email address in textblock with Gal search function(just like any email box, the "To" field will help you find email address), however when I deployed it in Windows 10 phone, a problem arose. After you selected an address, and type in another letter and delete that letter, the last address and the letter will be deleted at the same time instead of just delete the letter. It works fine in Windows 8.1 though. Any suggestion? After I drill down a little bit. I found something interesting about this piece of code

```
 private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Back && _textBox.SelectionStart <= 0)
        {
            RemoveLastItem();
        }

        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter && _textBox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            AddRecipient();
        }
    }
```

When you have something like this  xxx@somemail.com; g|------"|" is the cursor or caret.
In Windows 8.1, _textBox.SelectionStart == 1, but in Windows 10, _textBox.SelectionStart ==  0; thus caused the problem, any idea why this will happen?

Comment: According to your describe, I don't want do you want. So please put your code.

Comment: @JaydenGu I don't think there is anything in the code that has anything to do with BackSpace key, thus I didn't post the code. I'm thinking if I need to write my own backspace_key_pressed event

Comment: @JaydenGu I posted some code snippet for my new finding